# Flutter - Error "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>"

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

I tried running an application (let's call it project A) in Android Studio and get the error

`unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>`

I have googled the error and found that the error is usually solved by updating gradle plugin to version 4.1. The problem is, I cannot check, change, or update gradle plugin version since the "Project Structure" menu is missing. When I click menu bar File, I cannot find project structure anywhere. I can confirm, however, that the version of Android Studio is 4.1

I tried to make a new Android Project, and am very confused to see that in this new project, the project structure menu does appear. Furthermore, the gradle plugin version (as seen when I open project structure menu in this project) is actually 4.1

My question:

1. How can I solve the `unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>` error? The gradle plugin version seems to already be 4.1
2. Is gradle plugin version applied globally for all project? Or I need to define gradle plugin version for each project individually?
3. How can I make the project structure menu appear again when I make flutter project? (Sorry if this question is off-topic)

Additional information:

1. Flutter version is 1.20.3
2. Dart SDK version is 2.9.2
3. The project (project A) is previously written using VS Code

Please help, I'm a total newbie in Flutter and Android Studio

Thank You

Comment: Is it just a warning? This was a error previously but it didn't keep the app from being compiled

Comment: It says error and there is a message saying build failed in 1m 39s